# Flat Map that can go thru North Pole

Tags: coordinate-system, development, navigation, mercator

Is there any map SDK or tool that can show the navigation that passes through the north pole in a flat way? Basically If I use a Mercator projection map it is only flat and cannot show the north part of as how it is seen in a globe. I need something that will show a plane passing through the north pole in a 2D map.

Comment: Which software are you using? It sounds as though you just need to identify a suitable projection for use at the poles which is compatible with most packages (or web mapping frameworks) - see the [NOAA Arctic Map Catalogue](http://www.arctic.noaa.gov/maps.html) for examples, including the [UNEP Arctic Environment Atlas](http://maps.grida.no/arctic/).  This [introduction to polar projections & maps](http://www.geowebguru.com/2010/01/11/polar-maps-and-projections-part-1-overview/) may be useful.

Comment: I am developing an iOS app. Currently I am using WhirlyGlobe as my solution for showing a globe and a map. Globe is okay for getting through the north/south pole. However map version in WhirlyGlobe doesn't.

Comment: A static map or dynamic? What regions need to be shown, just the pole?

Comment: It looks like WhirlyGlobe only implements PlateCarree and Mercator, none of those projections are suitable for polar 2D mapping.You need something like "polar Azimuthal" projection. Are you willing to implement one yourself or are you looking for another WebApplication for your task ?

Comment: Basically I need just the countries and states. This is for a simple airplane navigation app. I'm trying to know if there are available solutions or toolkits that will be able to help me achieve the "polar azimuthal" projection in a map for navigation.

Comment: Azimuthal equidistant projection is your best bet in this scenario https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuthal_equidistant_projection

Comment: Actually found something that kinda works like my requirements. Problem is I don't know what they used for their map to project the map. The app is https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/jeppesen-mobile-fd/id446912582?mt=8.